# Privacy error:Your connection is not private

Tags: networking, google-chrome, facebook

[image]I am on Ubuntu 16.04.Since I came to this hotel,I am using wifi and have problems to connect to my facebook account.I have tried with Chrome,Vialid and Mozzila and I got all the time

```
Privacy error
Your connection is not private
```

I have synchronized my time so that is not the problem.

```
You cannot visit www.facebook.com right now because the website uses HSTS.
```

So how to solve this https versus http issue?

Comment: Did you do "Settings → Show advanced settings → Clear browsing data under Privacy option"? This error only in Chrome? Can you please post screenshot from Error in Firefox Private Mode?

Comment: It sounds like it's possible that the hotel wifi goes through a device or software that inspects web traffic, either to monitor its contents or inject ads or something. This would disrupt the normal encryption that https pages use, which would result in your web browser refusing to display the page. (It's also possible it's not the official hotel wifi at all, but a rogue access point designed to steal passwords!) In general, it's a good idea to use a VPN service whenever you're using a public wifi connection to help ensure your both your privacy and that you can connect to the sites you want.

Comment: @Fyodor Take a look at my edit please!

Comment: Maybe you are potential victim of Mitm attack?